CSS to fix unwanted space in list?
I'm working on rendering markdown for a project, and I'm facing an issue with styling nested lists using CSS. In the example below, you can see that there are unwanted spaces between the elements in each <li> item, which affects the alignment of the list indicators (like decimal or disc) with the content.
Here’s the HTML structure I'm using:
<h4 id="for-apache">For Apache:</h4>
<ol>
<li>
    <p><strong>Create a Virtual Host:</strong></p>
    <ul>
        <li>Open your Apache configuration file (usually found in <code>/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf</code> or <code>/etc/apache2/sites-available/</code>).</li>
        <li>Add the following configuration:</li>
    </ul>
    <pre>
        <code>
            &lt;VirtualHost *:80&gt;
                ServerName chatbot.example.com
                Redirect / http://example.com/chatbot
            &lt;/VirtualHost&gt;
        </code>
    </pre>
</li>
</ol>

Here’s a screenshot of the issue:

I want to remove the unexpected spaces between the list items without affecting the list type indicators. How can I adjust the CSS to eliminate these unwanted spaces?

The only two adjacent list items are "Open..." and "Add..." and there doesn't seem to be extra space between them. Do you mean the extra space under "Create..."? That's because you're surrounding it with a <p> tag. Try removing the tag and adding a <br> at the end of that line.

A <p> element is what is known as a "block-level" element. What's that mean?  MDN can tell you more than you'd ever want to know, but TL;DR it wants to be on a line all by itself at 100% width. That's why it's not sitting next to the <li> marker.
I'd recommend just removing that wrapping element entirely. If you need something to target with CSS, you can use <p>'s inline cousin, <span>, although you already have <strong>.
...And as an academic note, this would also fix the space if you were inclined to keep the tag: li > p { display: inline-block; }

Thanks! it helps me understand how <p> element works.

Have you tried removing the different margins and padding in your CSS?
If you haven't, here is what I think could help you:


ol, ul {
  list-style-position: inside; /* Aligns the bullet or number with the text */
  margin: 0; /* Removes default margins */
  padding: 0; /* Removes default padding */
}


li {
  margin: 0; /* Removes margin from list items */
  padding: 0.5em 0; /* Adjusts vertical spacing */
}

/* Optional: To further control spacing for nested lists */
ul {
  margin-left: 1.5em; /* Indent nested lists */
}
<h4 id="for-apache">For Apache:</h4>
<ol>
<li>
    <p><strong>Create a Virtual Host:</strong></p>
    <ul>
        <li>Open your Apache configuration file (usually found in <code>/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf</code> or <code>/etc/apache2/sites-available/</code>).</li>
        <li>Add the following configuration:</li>
    </ul>
    <pre>
        <code>
            &lt;VirtualHost *:80&gt;
                ServerName chatbot.example.com
                Redirect / http://example.com/chatbot
            &lt;/VirtualHost&gt;
        </code>
    </pre>
</li>
</ol>



